# agrupar resultado de sentencia mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

tengo esta sentencia.

```
select nombrem,idparcial,calificacion from calificacion
inner join parcial on parcial.idparcial=calificacion.fkparcial
inner join materia on materia.idmateria=calificacion.fkmateria;
```

y me da este resultado.

```
nombrem|idparcial|calificacion|
ingles |    1    |   10
ingles |    2    |   10
ingles |    3    |   10
POO    |    1    |   7
POO    |    2    |   7
POO    |    3    |   7
```

lo que quiero es que se agrupen por materia mas o menos algo asi

```
nombrem|idparcial|calificacion|idparcial|calificacion|idparcial|calificacion|
ingles |    1    |   10   |    2    |   10       |    3    |   10
POO    |    1    |   10   |    2    |   10       |    3    |   10
```

intente poner group by y con un multiple inner join pero no me queda de ningún modo.

```
create table cuatrimestre(
idcuatri int not null auto_increment,
primary key (idcuatri));

create table materia (
idmateria int not null auto_increment,
nombrem varchar(150) not null,
fkcuatri int not null,
primary key (idmateria),
foreign key (fkcuatri) references cuatrimestre (idcuatri));

create table parcial(
idparcial int not null auto_increment,
primary key (idparcial));

create table calificacion (
idcalificacion int not null auto_increment,
calificacion double not null,
fkparcial int not null,
fkmateria int not null,
primary key (idcalificacion),
foreign key (fkparcial) references parcial(idparcial),
foreign key (fkmateria) references materia (idmateria));
```

esta es mi base de datos, sera que la tengo mal estructurada? y en este caso,como seria la base de datos correctamente relacionada
de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, las materias tienes varios parciales y estos tienen asignados una calificación. Ciertamente tienes mal estructurada la base de datos, pues el parcial es quien debería tener la llave foránea de la materia, no la calificación. No obstante, la forma en la que deseas obtener la información sigue siendo un poco rara. Así que, si realmente necesitas esa estructura creo que podría ser más eficiente utilizar una base de datos como [Mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/), pues te permitirá estructurar con mayor libertad tus datos.

Sin embargo, para hacer la consulta que quieres puedes utilizar la siguiente sentencia:

```
select m.nombrem, c.p1, c.c1, c.p2, c.c2, c.p3, c.c3 from 
(select c1.fkmateria, 
c1.fkparcial as 'p1', c1.calificacion as 'c1',
c2.fkparcial as 'p2', c2.calificacion as 'c2',
c3.fkparcial as 'p3', c3.calificacion as 'c3'
from calificacion c1, calificacion c2, calificacion c3
where c1.idcalificacion != c2.idcalificacion 
and c1.idcalificacion != c3.idcalificacion
and c2.idcalificacion != c3.idcalificacion
and c1.fkmateria = c2.fkmateria
and c1.fkmateria = c3.fkmateria
group by c1.fkmateria) c 
INNER JOIN materia m ON c.fkmateria = m.idmateria;
```

Puedes probarla acá: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be56a/12/0).

Lo que estoy haciendo es multiplicar la tabla de calificaciones `n` veces, siendo n el número de parciales, y comprobando que las tres calificaciones son diferentes pero corresponde a la misma materia y luego las agrupo por materia. De esta forma, obtengo la estructura que deseas en el resultado y finalmente haces un `join` con la tabla materias para reemplazar el id de la materia con el nombre de ésta.

Comment: primero que todo, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder,es segundo decir que eres un crack, y tercero me podrías decir , como es que la base de datos debería estar relacionada para realizar lo que pido .

Comment: Para poder decirte si la estructura está realmente bien definida necesito saber más sobre lo que deseas hacer. Basado en lo que entendí pienso que podría mejorarse, pero no estoy seguro si entendí bien.

Comment: pues un control de calificaciones personal, las materias, sus calificaciones por parcial, su promedio, cuales fueron aprobadas y cuales reprobadas y bueno pues mi intelecto dio para eso ;p je je, gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo.

Comment: Entonces, un parcial siempre tendrá una única calificación?

Comment: si si, una materia puede tener 3 parciales y cada parcial solo puede tener una calificación.

Comment: Pues, la tabla de calificaciones sobra. La tabla de parciales debería tener el id de la materia a la que pertenece y su respectiva nota. Así sería mucho más simple y fácil hacer la consulta que buscas.

Comment: Bueno, realmente no lo hará más simple, la consulta casi que seguirá siendo igual. Lo que podrías hacer, debido a la forma en la que necesitas los datos es dejar sólo la tabla de materia y a ésta agregarle la información que necesitas ver (los 3 parciales y las 3 notas). Ciertamente no es la mejor opción, pero, cómo te digo, buscas un resultado un tanto extraño si usas únicamente sql.